# Accessing dict from another module in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

File1.py

```
john = {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'}
mark = {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'}
Will = {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
so on... and many more names
```

So my question is how do I access the values, lets say I want to know the age of a person by giving the person's name?

File2.py

```
from File1.py import *
#what should the code be to access the age 
#lets say I write 'john', I want to get his age

print john['Age'] # this is not how i want to access it

#
#any other way or methods ??
#
user_input=raw_input("enter a Name: ")
# user_input contains the name of the person I want to get the Age of
```

Comment: `john['Age']` is how you access it, how else did you have in mind? Your question is unclear.

Comment: @CoryKramer 
let's say :
name = raw_input("Enter a name")
now from this get me the age from the user input ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested dictionary to pass the person's name to the dictionary and then access the age via the key "Age":

```
john = {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'}
mark = {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'}
Will = {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
new_data = {"John":john, "Mark":mark, "Will":Will}
print(new_data["John"]["Age"])
```

Output:

```
35
```

Edit: Without a nested dictionary, you can try this:

```
john = {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'}
mark = {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'}
Will = {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
user_input=raw_input("enter a Name: ")
final_age = [b["Age"] for a, b in globals().items() if a == user_input][0]
```

Output:

```
35
```

Comment: you have recreated an entirely different senerio buddy :D

Comment: @DanteDevilhunter In that case, please clarify your question.

Comment: I have Upadated the Post please check.

Comment: Thanks for the response , Let me run it and will let you know if it worked

Comment: @DanteDevilhunter if this answer assisted you, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: it's throwing an error :
IndexError: list index out of range.

But i believe you have given me an idea close to my answer

Comment: @Dante you know nothing about code why you are wasting time here dude

Answer (score 1):

First of all in my opinion you should NOT do it like this. @Ajax1234 offers a much better solution, but to ask your question:

```
import File1

name = input('>>> Name: ')
print(getattr(File1, name)['Age'])  # 35
```

Does it

Comment: I agree, can you use `getattr` rather than `__dict__` though?

Comment: @Jared Goguen Yes, that would be much cleaner. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use get function in dictionary

```
print(john.get('age' , 0))
```

get take two parameter first the key then the default value to load if key not found

Comment: let's say i had hundreds of users ?
and i want to get the age dynamically from the name , then ??

Answer (score 0):

Next to a nested dictionary you can also use an import alias to make you code cleaner.

```
import File1 as employees
name = raw_input("Enter name:")
print(getattr(employees, name)['Age'])
```

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks for the suggestion, I am also only just a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) function. From documentation (emphasis mine):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, **not the module from which it is called**).

**Edit:**

As you are using separate files, you can create a function in the file File1.py that accepts the dictionary name and returns the appropriate value using the `globals()` function.

Usage:

`File1.py`

```
john = {'fullname':'John Wick', 'Age': 35 , 'job':'Hitman'}
mark = {'fullname':'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'}
Will = {'fullname':'Will smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}

def get_age(person):
    return globals()[person]['Age']
```

`File2.py`

```
import File1

person = input('Enter name:')
print(File1.get_age(person))
```

Comment: Thank You !! i will look into it ! you have sparked an idea into me ! Cheers !!

Comment: @Dante You're welcome. Note the documentation quote I have put in. You can still use this approach for your case even with multiple files. Just make a function in the File1.py that accepts the name of the dictionary, and returns the `Age`, or whatever you want.

Comment: When you use globals() , it becomes a list so you have to access it by integer , this is complicating my problem.

Comment: @Dante No it doesn't become a list. Look at the documentation. Plus, I have given a working example, try that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you are saving each of these dicts into a separate variable instead of just using a nested dict like

```
persons = {
    'john': {'fullname': 'John Wick', 'Age': 35, 'job': 'Hitman'},
    'mark': {'fullname': 'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'},
    'will': {'fullname': 'Will Smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
}
```

with which you could use user input to access the `persons` dict's keys,
if you really want to name your *variables* based on their *values* (which  does not make much sense to me since it's not really variable after), you can use Python's `globals()` and `locals()` function.

file1.py

```
john = {'fullname': 'John Wick', 'Age': 35, 'job': 'Hitman'}
mark = {'fullname': 'Mark Zuckerberg', 'Age': 30, 'job': 'Developer'},
will = {'fullname': 'Will Smith', 'Age': 45, 'job': 'Actor'}
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import *

name = raw_input('Please enter a name:')
global_vars = globals()

print(global_vars[name])
```

But still, since you could just use a nested dict I see no single valid reason to use `globals()` for this use case at all. Just declare your dicts under keys in another dict and you should be just fine.

Comment: i have a file with 5000 lines of dict data in similar fashion , so i need to use them currently.
i came here to ask if anyone has an idea to get the desired results.

Comment: btw ! your code would throw an Error.
When you use globals() , it becomes a list so you have to access it by integer , so it would be an error.

Comment: @DanteDevilhunter In fact his code works, you just have to read the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to see that `globals()` returns a dictionary. Still if you have 5000+ lines of dicts maybe you are better off parsing the file and saving it as a json file, csv file, create a database or something like that.